# How can I get window thumbnails when hovering over unity bar application icons?

Tags: unity, compiz

I am pretty sure that after installing 11.10 when an application had two or more windows open and I hovered over a unity bar icon with little white arrows (one for each window), I was getting a window thumbnail for each window of that application.

But I don't see that any more.

Does anyone know how to restore that?

Answer (score 5):

1. Be sure to install both compizconfig-settings-manager (CompizConfig
   Settings Manager or CCSM) and compiz-plugins-extra. You can do this
   from Ubuntu Software Centre.
2. Open CCSM > Extras > Enable Window Previews (turn this on) > Taskbar
   Shows Only Windows Of Current Viewport (uncheck).

[image: Enable Windows Previews in CCSM]

This will do as you wish.

Comment: I remember on older ubuntu versions like 11.04 there was a script and it enabled it on side menu, I just can not find it any more

Comment: I was wrong. You are correct. I have fixed my reply. Try it and let us know if it works for you.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 and I followed these instructions, but there is no "Enable Window Previews" in the Extras section of ccsm. Why is that?

Comment: Is there a way to integrate this into Plank dock in Ubuntu budgie + unity?

Comment: @Jonathan Ubuntu no longer uses Compiz (I don't know about Budgie), so it's best that you ask this question afresh, or maybe on the [Budgie support forum](https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/).

Comment: Wow just tested it and it does work out of the box with Plank as well (Cosmic). BTW Unity works fine in the latest Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

You probably activated scale mode for the open windows by clicking the icon (with multiple windows open), since the window previews are disabled by default (due to a not-so-hot implementation of the feature).

In fact, that plugin does not work so well with Unity, so you would be better off using a dock.

From your comments, it seems like you did something to mess with the settings that has disabled the scale mode. If you don't mind having to add your favourites to the launcher again, you can run:

`unity --reset`

Also, by the way, installing a dock is simple. Open the Software Center and search for "dock", and then choose one you like. The are some good ones such as Avant Window Navigator, Cairo Dock, and Docky. All three support showing the window previews, but not for multiple windows.

For that, you would need to install DockBarX, and use it in a standalone way.

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dockbar-main/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install dockbarx
 sudo apt-get install dockbarx-themes-extra
```

Then run `dockbarx`. You can modify the options show that it activates scale mode when there are multiple windows open and you click on it.

Comment: So if they are disabled by default, how do i enable them? how do i use a dock?

Comment: Hang on, I went to compiz config settings manager and activated window preview, but now a preview comes when hovering, not when clicking and it only shows one of the windows of that app... I was refering to a feature that shows a preview of all the windows open for that application... any idea?

Comment: @SoftwareDevelopmentPerth I mentioned it in my answer. When you click the icon of an application that has multiple windows open, you will get a preview of all the open windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an app with more than one open window, there are a few ways to display previews. If you have one of that apps windows focused, then you can click the launcher entry once to get a big overview with previews. To switch between windows of a single app, with previews, you can press Alt+BAT (Button Above Tab).

There is no preview on hover by default.

Comment: It doesn't work when doing single click either. Is there any setting to enable/disable this? I was playing with compiz config settings, maybe i stuffed somthing up...

Comment: Make sure that the Scale plugin is enabled in ccsm. If you wish to also get a window title overlay while in the spread (preview) then enable the Scale Addons & Text plugins