# ubuntu 12.10 software window thumbnail previews

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get window thumbnails when hovering over unity bar application icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77787/how-can-i-get-window-thumbnails-when-hovering-over-unity-bar-application-icons)

I want to know if there is an easy way to enable software window thumbnail previews like you get in windows os it would save me a lot of time 
[image]
thank you for your time